# Set-Cookie 'expires' attribute parse error due to format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

Using `Rails 4.0.0` and `Ruby ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]` seems to fail parsing the `expires` attribute of the `Set-Cookie` header.

```
HTTP Response 

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: auth=YWRtaW46MTM5MDI5NzA4MzNjk3MjZjNWI1N2NjMjQzMjE2MjJlYjpBQklRVU8;
    Expires=Wed, 23-Jan-2014 09:38:02 GMT; Path=/api; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5AF33D5F3ED6741038E14202935A0AD5.node1; Path=/api/; HttpOnly
```

Logging the `cookies object` in the controller ouputs:

```
{"auth"=>"YWRtaW46MTM5MDI5NzA4MzNjk3MjZjNWI1N2NjMjQzMjE2MjJlYjpBQklRVU8", "Expires"=>"Wed", "Path"=>"%2Fapi%2F", "JSESSIONID"=>"4F9344E3A75554E26206FD32F1793AD5.node1"}
```

Here I see two problems.

- The parsing of the attribute outputs only "Wed"
- JSESSIONID cookie is missing the path

I couldn't find anything in `Rails issues` and googling. I've been also looking through the documentation and I couldn't find nothing relevant to this problem.

So I think that I might be overlooking or missing a configuration property to explicitly say to `Rails` the `Expires` attribute format.

Comment: This is not a rails problem. `CGI::Cookie#parse` is a wrecker. Currently trying to understand, WTP.

Comment: It looks like that’s a [well-known problem](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=1698&aid=1972&group_id=426), nobody cares about. I suggest you to parse it by hand, though.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks I will look how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse cookies this code might help.

```
out = "Expires=Wed, 23-Jan-2014 09:38:02 GMT; Path=/api; HttpOnly"
out.split(';').map { |c| c.split('=') }.inject({}) { |result, element|     result[element.first] = element.last;  result }
```